# Raw Query Union All laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this query

```
select n as monthnum, monthname(100*n+1) as month, 0 as usr
from (
    select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9 union all select 10 union all select 11 union all select 12
) q

UNION ALL

SELECT Monthnum, Month, SUM(usr) as jumlah
FROM
(
    SELECT MONTH(t.created_at) AS monthnum, MONTHNAME(t.created_at) AS Month, 1 AS usr FROM job_applications t
    WHERE YEAR(t.created_at) = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND MONTH(t.created_at) < 12 and job_id = 2
) q
    
GROUP BY monthnum, Month
ORDER BY monthnum
```

**How i get data from laravel ?**

I am already try

```
JobApplication:select(Raw(Query))
```

Always get error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can

use DB

```
$test_query = "select n as monthnum, monthname(100*n+1) as month, 0 as usr
from (
    select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9 union all select 10 union all select 11 union all select 12
) q

UNION ALL

SELECT Monthnum, Month, SUM(usr) as jumlah
FROM
(
    SELECT MONTH(t.created_at) AS monthnum, MONTHNAME(t.created_at) AS Month, 1 AS usr FROM job_applications t
    WHERE YEAR(t.created_at) = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND MONTH(t.created_at) < 12 and job_id = 2
) q
    
GROUP BY monthnum, Month
ORDER BY monthnum";


$test_results = DB::select($test_query);
```